# android:onClick attribute is not working through data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

Here is my code for Fragment class.

```
class FragmentOne : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
        val binding: FragmentOneBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    fun onClicking(){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
}
```

And here is my code for Fragment XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".FragmentOne">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="clickable"
            type="com.example.fragmentpractise1.FragmentOne" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hola Gola"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="@{()-> clickable.onClicking()}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now what I am trying to understand, why `android:onClick` is not showing any toast result. On pressing the button nothing happens. I can show toast by setting `onClickListener` on button id in Fragment class but unable to show toast via `onClick` attribute in XML using databinding.

Comment: You have not defined a value for `clickable`. You inflate the binding, but you do not then do anything with the binding to tell it what the value of `clickable` is. So, data binding sees `clickable` as being `null`. Fortunately, it suppresses `NullPointerExceptions`, so you are not crashing (though there might still be some messages in Logcat -- I forget).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `clickable.onClicking()` in xml which is not set yet. When you instantiate a data binding object, you probably have to set its variables as well (like `clickable` in your example)

Set that variable after instantiation like this

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
        val binding: FragmentOneBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
        binding.clickable = this // your fragment
        return binding.root
    }
```

Also using `v` instead of `()` inside onClick is a bit more rational because that's a lambda in Java syntax receiving one view argument. I suggest to change it to below for more readability

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hola Gola"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="@{ v -> clickable.onClicking()}"/>
```

Comment: It's solved. But I still have a doubt. While declaring variable " clikcable " I declared the type as well. So is it needed all the time to instantiate in fragment as well? Helpful if you can clarify more on this topic.

Comment: Yes you have to do it because even when you declare the type, compiler and runtime cannot guess which object from that type is suitable for your variable. But you can make use of reflection to do it. This is not an easy task though. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67782173/1905965) to give an idea about what you can do in your BaseFragment. After using that function, you will have the binding class which you can invoke `inflate` function on it to get the binding. And you can take advantage of another reflection call to set that variable inside it with a fixed name.

Comment: This method is so complicated, extremely reduces readability of your code and out of the context of this question. But you can ask another question about"magically" setting the objects inside data binding and probably me and other folks here can come with better approaches

Comment: Got it now. Thanks a lot!