# Crash from Permission

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-permissions

I'm trying to take permission to change imageView with another image from library that users choose. So, I connected RecipesFragment with MainActivity with NavHostFragment.But when I try to run the app it's giving crash and closing up.You can see the code , crashes from logcat down there and the problems.(The onclick Id of imageView2 is chooseImage from xml)

```kotlin
class RecipesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentRecipesBinding

    var choosenPicture : Uri? = null
    var choosenBitmap : Bitmap? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentRecipesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }

    fun chooseImage(view: View) {


        activity.let {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //There is no permission already so we need to take permission
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
                //If it doesnt work use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

            }else{
                //There is already permission so, there is no need to take permission again
                val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,2)

            }

        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if(requestCode == 1){

            if(grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //We have permission now
                val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,2)
            }
        }


        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){

            choosenPicture = data.data

        }

        try{

            context?.let {
                if(choosenPicture != null){
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28){
                        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(it.contentResolver,choosenPicture!!)
                        choosenBitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                        binding.imageView2.setImageBitmap(choosenBitmap)

                    }else{
                        choosenBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(it.contentResolver,choosenPicture)
                        binding.imageView2.setImageBitmap(choosenBitmap)
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

> E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.alperenavan.recipes, PID: 9811
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method chooseImage(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'imageView2'
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:506)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:464)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)`

[image: Problems]

I tried to make an imageView which can be changed from users photo gallery with permission but when I try to take permission and run the app it crashed.

Comment: I recommend that you use setOnClickListener in your Kotlin code in the Fragment instead of setting the click listener in the xml, you will have more control, have access to the view and onClick in the xml creates a click listener behind the scenes anyways.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944233/androidonclick-attribute-is-not-working-through-data-binding

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is trying to find the method `chooseImage()` in your `Activity`, not in your `Fragment`, which is why it is crashing. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene